# How can I extract the 3 "Yield on Cost" values at the top of this page: https://seekingalpha.com/symbol/GE/dividends/yield-on-cost?

Tags: xpath, google-sheets

I can't figure out the correct XPath to use in Google Sheets for extracting the 3 (three) "Yield on Cost" values at the top of this page:  https://seekingalpha.com/symbol/GE/dividends/yield-on-cost

Or the 5 (five) "Growth" values at the top of this page:  https://seekingalpha.com/symbol/GE/dividends/dividend-growth

I have read many informative webpages on the subject of using both IMPORTXML and IMPORTHTML within Google Sheets, and I have had good success in the past -- but I am coming up empty on these two pages. This is likely due to me missing some fundamental problem that others would probably see and understand immediately.

How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`https://seekingalpha.com/` site can't be scraped because it depends on JavaScript and Google Sheets can't work with JavaScript at all. You can see yourself if you disable JS temporarily:

[image: 0]